# Best Practice of Archive Data in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have a requirement of archive the Data in Cosmos DB to ADLS Gen2 daily, I am not sure if we have any best practice of doing this.
The collection we need to archive has over 100M documents each day(about 120K per minute). The document size is around 0.5k each so, total data size is around 50-60G. We only have insertion and no update of the documents.

What I can think of are following 2 ways:
1.  Using Data Factory to extract the data each day and copy it to ADLS Gen2.
2.  Using the change feed of Cosmos DB to monitor any insert and call Azure Function to insert the same document to ADLS Gen2.

I am not sure what is our suggested way.
From my check both of the solution has some drawbacks. The ADF connection to Cosmos DB seems not stable, if the data volume is not large, it is suitable. When I try to load the 100M documents data, it always failed with data connection errors. For the change feed, due to the insertion is very large, we might need to call Azure Function 100M times per day, it will bring a lot of cost concerns of customer and I am not 100% sure if it is a good way to use change feed for such huge insert scenario.

Do we have any other ways for Data Archive in Cosmos DB?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you? If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cost is priority by your description,so let's compare the cost firstly.

Azure Function price: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/

[image]

You said 120K data per minute and every document is around 0.5K. So it means that you get 240 documents per minute. For one month, it should be around `240*60*24*30 = 10,368,000`

So the calculate as below,just for your reference.This is rough because the execution time and memory depend on the truly usage.

[image]

For example,if the execution time of azure function is `0.1` second,not `1` second.Then :

[image]

ADF price: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/

You said ADF seems not stable,i would this is drawback of ADF.ADF is nice tool for data archiving. I'm afraid that the concurrency exceeds the default [DIU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#data-integration-units).I'd suggest you trying to raise DIU to try again.

My idea:

Per my experience,maybe you need to pay more attention to consistence.If the data must be archived in real time due to strong consistency, you can choose azure function.On the contrary, I strongly recommend that you process it in the batch.For example,execute ADF copy activity once every day to process the data in last day.